# Geometry of a free radical at the bridgehead carbon

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, reference-request, radicals

With reference to [*J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1968,** *90* (19), 5266–5267](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01021a037), they state:

> The most favorable geometry of aliphatic free radicals remains an unsolved problem, since existing data are consistent with a geometry which is either pyramidal and rapidly inverting, or planar but easily deformed.<sup>2-4</sup> One approach to the problem is generation of the radical
> at a bridgehead of a bridged bicyclic system. [...] From their aldehyde decarbonylation study, however, Applequist and Kaplan concluded that 1 -adamantyl and 1 -bicyclo[2.2.2]octyl were appreciably more stable than t-butyl. <sup>3</sup>
> 3. [*J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1965,** *87* (10), 2194–2200](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01088a018)

which is later concluded as:

> [...] The extent of geometrical destabilization is considerable, and we conclude that alkyl radicals tend toward planar geometry. The lesser extent of destabilization, relative to that for the carbonium ions, might mean that radicals seek a flattened pyramidal state. [...] This issue can evidently not be settled without spectroscopic information about alkyl radicals.

Has there been any further studies on the geometry of free radicals at the bridgehead carbon?

Comment: If you have access to Science Citation Index, you may locate more recent work.

Comment: @user55119 unfortunately I do not.. Could you share a reference if possible?

Comment: I found 115. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: These 2 are dated but perhaps of interest. STABILITY OF ADAMANT-1-YL RADICAL 
JOURNAL OF THE CHEMICAL SOCIETY D-CHEMICAL COMMUNICATIONS  Issue: ‏ 5   Pages: ‏ 216-&   Published: ‏ 1969 
. 
BRIDGEHEAD FREE RADICAL STABILITY . DECOMPOSITION OF T-BUTYLPEROXYESTERS OF 1-ADAMANTYL 1-BICYCLO[2.2.]OCTYL AND 1-NORBORNYL SYSTEMS 
CANADIAN JOURNAL OF CHEMISTRY  Volume: ‏ 46   Issue: ‏ 19   Pages: ‏ 3099-&   Published: ‏ ‏ 1968

Comment: @user55119 Thanks.. I was also able to find a comprehensive paper regarding bridgehead radicals [*Chem. Soc. Rev.* **1992,** *21* (2), 105](https://doi.org/10.1039/cs9922100105) by John C. Walton

Comment: @SafdarFaisal: So is the answer to the question "why can free radicals form at bridge head carbon whereas carbocations cannot...?" is because a carbocation is $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridized whereas a free radical would not be $\ce{sp^2}$, it's not $\ce{sp^3}$ as well, but something in between. And $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridization is not allowed as per Bredt's rule. Am I right?

Comment: @user55119 Sir please see my above comment, is my explanation for stable existence of free radical at bridge head positions correct? If not, why can a free radical exist at bridge head position then?