Can the bridge head carbon of a bicyclic ring be a free radical?
I am confused whether free radicals exist at the bridge head carbon position because a free radical has sp2 hybridization which I have studied is not possible for a bridge head carbon due to angle strain reasons. However I came across a question in which the product formed by photobromination had bromine attached to the bridge head carbon. Please help me understand.

https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1992/cs/cs9922100105/unauth and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/140166/geometry-of-a-free-radical-at-the-bridgehead-carbon might be of interest.

Radicals aren't necessarily flat

@Mithoron oh so is it because the free radical has an pyramidal shape and the alone electron is not in the plane of the bicyclic ring?

Bridge-head radicals are generally unstable due to angle strain and hybridization issues. However, if the resulting product from a reaction, like photobromination, is much more stable, the reaction can proceed, making it thermodynamically and kinetically favorable despite the initial instability. – Unknown
This is similar to bridge-head carbocations which are necessarily unstable due to the reasons you have mentioned but such some bridgehead carbocations known as non - classical carbocations are stable due to teeny tiny delocalization of their positive charge around other atoms around. Since the product formed usually after $S_N1$ reaction of some such compounds is more stable than original compound, they are forced to go to the transition state. Even though the activation energy is high but the energy released after the reaction is more and it is thermodynamically and kinetically favourable, hence as such, it undergoes the reaction.
You can refer to this answer as well which I found helpful: Bridgehead carbocation: Violation of Bredt's Rule

Well, but the q. is about radicals.

@Mithoron My bad, I was negligent and thanks for pin-pointing. Should I delete the answer because I am rather not sure about radicals?

Well, If you wish, but researching some more and adding about radicals would be preferable.
